# Need help translating T-SQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-functions

I just want a translation of a simple procedure that returns the amount of clients in a specific area (area_id), to use it in PostgreSQL.

The code in T-SQL is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findGeoClients
    @area_id INT 
AS
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS clients_in_that_area 
    FROM clients 
    WHERE area_id = @area_id
```

I tried converting it using sqlines.com/online but I am constantly getting syntax errors.

Comment: PL/SQL is used with Oracle. Rephrase your title and question for PostgreSQL and remove the plsql tag.

Answer (score 1):

Procedures aren't meant to return anything, you need a function. But you don't need PL/pgSQL for this. A simple SQL function will do:

```
CREATE function findgeoclients(p_area_id int)
  returns bigint
AS
$$
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS clients_in_that_area 
  FROM clients 
  WHERE area_id = p_area_id;
$$
language sql
stable;
```

Comment: And if I'd want a procedure (to use in PosgreSQL) that would just print the results?

Comment: Postgres isn't SQL Server, if you want to return something use a function. If you want to "print" the result, simply use `select findgeoclients(42);`